# Installing Scrapy on windows 7 with python 2.7.3 gives error

Tags: python, screen-scraping

easy_install scarpy on command prompt says scrapy is not a recognized archive type. Help!

**Error Message:** "error: Not a recognized archive type: Scrapy"

Comment: Show in your question what message error exactly you see?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a few dependencies of scrapy won't installed automatically from easy_install and you have to do it manually.

1. Install binary version of Twisted
2. install binary version of lxml
3. install Scrapy

Hope that this will solve your error message. If not, check this [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/NQGltXNNt1I) with someone that had the same problem as you.

Comment: I already have installed all of them. the egg files, lxml, twisted, openSSL etc.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the two files that mentioned on the link I gave you. They said that this will solve the problem if you have already installed these libraries.

Comment: yea was about to try that one but the same command suddenly worked. I could not understand the mistake i was making as both the commands were exactly same. but it ran. so yes. done with the installation now! thanks a heap!